# Can I use residual as control variable?

Tags: least-squares

Let's say I want to see the effect of X1 on Y. I know X2 also has an effect on Y and I also know X1 has an effect on X2. Therefore, X1 can have an effect on Y directly and through X2. X1 and X2 are both continuous variables.

Normally, I would do Y = X1 + X2 + e. However, due to the high correlation between X1 and X2, I find an insignificant coefficient for X1. Is it proper for me to orthogonalize X1 and X2 by doing X2 = X1 + e and then using the residual of this regression in place of X2, i.e., Y = X1 + residual + e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two models are equivalent. 
First model is:

$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + e$

In the second model, residual is $X_2-a - bX_1$.

Then the second model is:

$Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1X_1 + \alpha_2(X_2-a - bX_1) + e$

After simplifying the second model, you will find the relationship between $\alpha$s and $\beta$s.